# ¿XAMPP me rechaza la conexión con los dispositivos conectados a la misma red?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, windows10, localhost

Instale XAMPP para un proyecto de WordPress en localhost, hice todo los pasos necesarios para la instalación, y todo perfecto al parecer, en la computadora que hice la instalación si puedo acceder a la red local, pero a los demás dispositivos conectados a esta misma red me rechaza la conexión, ya les di permiso de administrador para que se ejecute XAMPP correctamente, pero aparece este mismo error al querer conectarme desde otro dispositivo, de que rechaza la conexión.

Comment: Hola Mr. Smile Arts, podrías mostrarnos el mensaje de error completo, y toda información que consideres pertinente, a fin de poder darte una respuesta?, gracias.

Comment: Y muestra como quieres acceder desde las otras PC's.

Comment: Me dice: **No se puede acceder a este sitio. localhost rechazado tu conexión. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. Y quiero acceder como "localhost/wordpress/" @OCHOA

Comment: Me dice: **No se puede acceder a este sitio. localhost rechazado tu conexión. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.** Y quiero acceder como "localhost/wordpress/" @MarcePuente

Answer (score 0):

> Me dice: No se puede acceder a este sitio. localhost rechazado tu conexión. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Y quiero acceder como "localhost/wordpress/" @OCHOA

Jamás vas a poder llegarle así. Eso significa que vas iniciando en este mundo y necesitas ver como funciona un servidor web, Apache en tu caso.

Primero, **Apache es tu servidor web**. La función esencial del servidor Apache es servir las webs alojadas en el/tu servidor a los diversos navegadores como Chrome, Firefox, Safari, o también a otras computadoras ya sea en una **Red local (LAN)** o en internet.

En una red LAN, tu computadora siempre es el **localhost**, por eso funciona en tu PC. Pero para acceder desde otras computadoras debes indicar en el navegador la dirección de tu maquina. En internet tu pones la url de una web y listo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Pero en una red LAN las PC's se identifican por la **IP**, entonces para acceder a la PC donde esta tu web Wordpress debes hacerlo por medio de la IP de tu servidor: [http://192.168.1.2/wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), asumiendo que tu PC tenga la IP: 192.168.1.2

También lo puedes hacer por nombre de equipo: http://tuServidor/wordpress

Luego de eso, pueda que si tienen configurados el **Firewall** pueda que necesites hacer alguna que otra **regla de entrada/salida** en algunas computadoras.

Intententalo y nos comentas. Eso si, he marcado unas palabras en **Negrita** en esta respuesta, es tu deber y obligación investigar y leer sobre eso, sino recibirás poca ayuda ya que fomentamos ser autodidactas y nos gusta el esfuerzo de quienes preguntan.